# Weird memory issues, with ARC enabled

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, delegates, automatic-ref-counting

I am having a very, very strange error, probably related to memory management (even though I'm using ARC).

I have a my AppDelegate, Foo, and SubFoo (which is a subclass of Foo).

Foo.h

```
@protocol FooDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)didReceiveDownloadRequest:(NSURLRequest *)downloadRequest;

@end

@interface Foo : NSObject {
    __weak id <FooDelegate> delegate;
}

- (void)performRequest;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <FooDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *fileIdentifier;
```

Foo.m

```
@implementation Foo

@synthesize delegate, fileIdentifier;

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.delegate = nil; // I tried leaving this line out, same result.
        NSLog(@"I am %p.", self);
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)performRequest {
    // Bah.
}

@end
```

SubFoo.h

```
@interface SubFoo : Foo {
    WebView *aWebView;
}
```

SubFoo.m

```
- (void)performRequest {
    if (self.fileIdentifier) {
        aWebView = [[WebView alloc] init];
        [aWebView setFrameLoadDelegate:self];
        [[aWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"theURL"]];
    }
}

- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    NSLog(@"Finished loading.");

    // ...

    NSLog(@"Class Name: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]));
    NSLog(@"Memory Location of delegate: %p", self.delegate);

    // ...
}
```

Sometimes, the class name on webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: returns a completely different class (instead of SubFoo, it returns random classes, like NSSet, NSArray, it even sometimes returns CFXPreferencesSearchListSource), other times it just crashes there with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS, and when it returns a random class on Class Name: it returns that [randomClassName delegate] is an unrecognized selector.

**EDIT**: When self gets set to another thing, it gets set RIGHT on webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:, and on performRequest it is ALWAYS SubFoo.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: (Sorry, this was a misunderstanding - deleted)

Comment: Is your `WebView` a property? Also, just wondering, why are you using `retain` instead of `strong`, which is the new convention for ARC?

Comment: @MishieMoo `retain` and `strong` are exactly the same, and anyway for a NSString it should be `copy` instead.

Comment: I wasn't talking about the `NSString` but the `WebView` on the `SubFoo` object. If it's not strong/retain then it could possibly be getting autoreleased by ARC.

Comment: aWebView is not a property. Tried setting it to __strong, but same thing.

Comment: How are you creating `SubFoo`? What is holding a reference to it?

Comment: Another class is holding a reference to it, initted by SubFoo *theClass = [[SubFoo alloc] init];. I tried doing it as __strong SubFoo *theClass = [[SubFoo alloc] init]; but the result was the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, even though you are using ARC zeroing weak references in your project (`@property (weak)`), other projects and frameworks may not be (and are probably not) using zeroing weak references.

In other words, assume that all delegates in frameworks are `__unsafe_unretained` unless:

1. The delegate property is declared `weak` in a header
2. The documentation/header explicitly states otherwise

---

That said, let's talk about your example.  Your object ownership chart looks something like this:

[image: Object ownership chart]

(Note: I'm not entirely sure which class in your project uses SubFoo.  Based on common practice, I'm assuming that you have a class with a strong reference to SubFoo, and that class is also set up to be a SubFooDelegate)

Ultimately, your instance of SubFoo is losing its last strong reference and is deallocating.  In a perfect ARC-enabled world, the WebView's pointer to SubFoo would nil out at this time.  However, it's not a perfect world yet, and WebView's frameLoadDelegate is `__unsafe_unretained`.  Due to run loop interaction, the WebView is outliving SubFoo.  The web request completes, and a dead pointer is dereferenced.

To fix this, you need to call `[aWebView setFrameLoadDelegate:nil];` in SubFoo's dealloc method.  You also need to call it when you reassign aWebView, as you are losing track of the old aWebView:

SubFoo.m

```
@implementation SubFoo

- (void)dealloc {
    [aWebView setFrameLoadDelegate:nil];
    // Also nil out any other unsafe-unretained references
}

- (void)performRequest {
    if (self.fileIdentifier) {
        [aWebView setFrameLoadDelegate:nil]; // Protects us if performRequest is called twice.  Is a no-op if aWebView is nil
        aWebView = [[WebView alloc] init];
        [aWebView setFrameLoadDelegate:self];
        [[aWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"theURL"]];
    }
}

- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Note: I'm fairly sure that you have two issues here.  One is the crash/delegate issues.  The other issue is that your SubFoo is dying too early.  After fixing the crash, you probably want to follow CRD/mohsenr's advice to address the early dying.

Comment: Your answers have helped me understand that the problem os that dealloc is indeed being ran in SubFoo. I am calling SubFoo using __strong. 

This is the way I am doing it: Class1 is calling Class2, using __strong and Class2 is calling SubFoo, using __strong too. Both SubFoo and Class2 are being deallocated, but Class1 is never deallocated. This is a server app acting as a webserver, so I am trying to get some data from a client, returning an answer saying I got that answer and then doing some jobs on the background. Class1 is the http class.

Comment: Can we see more code from Class1 which interacts with Class2?  That could help us better diagnose why Class2 is going away early. Regardless, you need to clear the setFrameLoadDelegate: weak reference in SubFoo (as shown above) to prevent crashes.

Comment: Posting the code here made the code look bad, so pasted it: http://pastie.org/private/wj17gej0b0y8wfzw9nc0ma That is the part of that class that interacts with Class2.

Comment: 1) You don't need to declare theClient as __strong - variables by default are __strong.  2) After onSocket:didAcceptNewSocket: finishes, only the clientConnections NSArray has a strong reference to Class2.  Can I see the declaration of clientConnections and where you initialize it?

Comment: (Hope it comes out understandable) .h NSMutableArray *clientConnections; .m - (id)initServerWithPort:(int)thePort delegate:(id)theDelegate {
 if (self = [super init]) {
  // ...
  clientConnections = [NSMutableArray new];

Comment: That looks fine (as long as you aren't overwriting the clientConnections array later).  Set a breakpoint in Class2.dealloc and see why Class2 is going away early.  Did the crash go away with the code modifications I made above?

Comment: Yes, the crash went away with that code modifications, as now didFinishLoadForFrame doesn't get run at all. Anyway, I set the breakpoint. What am I supposed to be looking for?

Comment: didfinishLoadForFrame: won't be called if Class2 has gone away.  This is good, it means your cleanup code works and you are properly clearing your weak references.  Now it's time to tackle why Class2 is going away early.  The backtrace shown when breaking on Class2.dealloc may provide hints.  You can also use the Allocations tool in Instruments.  I don't see any remaining ownership issues in the code snippets you have pasted - the clientConnections array should be holding onto Class2.  My guess is that you are nil'ing it out somewhere, or the instance owning clientConnections is going away.

Answer (score 1):

Forget the `self.delegate` error for now, it is a red herring if `[self class]` is producing the wrong result! Your results suggest you are somehow clobbering `self`.

Breakpoint on `webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:` check the `self` value and step through.

**Comment Followup**

For self to be wrong on the first statement of an instance method is, let's say, unusual (but not impossible).

It is important when an object is set as another's delegate that you make sure the delegate object's lifetime is at least as long as the one it is acting as a delegate to. Introducing ARC can make previously working code fail as it may release the delegate earlier than the code did under MRC. When this happens the call to the delegate usually fails.

However your error does not fail on the call to the delegate; the call starts - you end up in `webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:` - and then you find `self` is invalid. To actually invoke an instance method *usually* requires a valid value for `self` as it is used to determine the method implementation to call. Hence it is usual for `self` to be valid at the start of a method!

But note the "usually"...

So despite you having successfully reach your method, your error might be down to not having a strong reference to your `SubFoo` instance, you pass it as a delegate to `aWebView`, and by the time `webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:` is called your `SubFoo` has gone.

Make sure you're keeping a strong ref to your `SubFoo instance`. If you just want to test (this is **not** a recommended general solution!) if this is your problem you can just assign it to a local static (`static SubFoo *holdMe` say declared inside `performRequest`) in `performRequest`, which will keep a strong reference around at least until the next call to `performRequest`. If this does prove to be the problem you then need to come up with a good way to maintain the reference that fits your design.

Comment: Wasn't sure how to check the self value using gdb, so I just did NSLog(@"%@ %p", self, self); right after webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:. First, it crashed with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I tried to run it again, and this time it outputted (
    "<WebHTMLView: 0x10232ac90>"
) 0x102301060. Which means that self is really getting clobbered, somehow...

Comment: The NSLog statement that you are currently using works fine. You can even omit the call of NSStringFromClass as the class method retuns an object of type Class which is perfectly capable of describing iself. In your xcode while debugging split the debugger window into two. (see the icons in the top right of the debugging console part of the window and chose the one in the middle). Then in the left hand pane within the debug window you will see self, its class and poperties and its superclass and properties and so on. If that does not work then repeat your NSLog after each statement.

Comment: Did that. Sometimes self gets set to random things right on the webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:.

Comment: Take one step more, it is not uncommon for arguments not to show valid values if you break right on the method start itself. If you break on your first `NSLog(@"Finished loading.");` they should be OK. Now step and watch, at what point in your `// ...` code do things go awry?

Comment: Right on the first NSLog (NSLog(@"%@ %p", self, self);), things go awry most of the times. When it says it is another class, it all goes good until I request for the delegate of the current object, where it says then the selector delegate] is unrecognized, and when it detects itself as a SubFoo, it then throws a EXC_BAD_ACCESS right after.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the real problem: You're creating a SubFoo object within the context of a method. So after the method completes, SubFoo is being released (before its WebView has time to load).

To fix this, you'll need to assign the SubFoo object you're creating to something persistent, like a instance variable of the class you're creating it from. That way the object will persist beyond the scope of the method it was created in and all will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As CRD mentioned, I would say an incorrect object/bad access returned is a sign of an object being released. Sometimes it's replaced by another object, sometimes it's not so you get the bad access exception. Regarding how this could happen to `self`, I would imagine that this is a concurrency weird case (object is being freed on another thread).

The best way to confirm this is to run your code in Instrument's NSZombie template, it'll show you as soon as you access a freed object. It also shows when it's been retained/released so you don't have to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your above comment.

```
SubFoo *theClass = [[SubFoo alloc] init];
```

You must store theClass in a

```
@property (strong)  SubFoo *mySubFoo;
```

If you declare it as such:

```
{
    SubFoo *theClass = [[SubFoo alloc] init];
}
```

It gets released at the closing bracket. This part of the point of ARC when that variable moves out of scope, it gets released. If you want to let it float in the ether you could use

```
{
    __weak SubFoo *theClass = [[SubFoo alloc] init];
}
```

and it won't get released, but this will lead to a memory leak unless you carefully manage all the weak references. In the case of it not being released at -performRequest I'm assuming the request looks like this:

```
{
    SubFoo *theClass = [[SubFoo alloc] init];
    [theClass performRequest];
}
```

wheras -webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: is called at some indiscriminate time in the future.